# How do I change Outfile name using variable in Visual C++ linker?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker

In the linker the binary destination is specified as:

```
$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe
```

Example:

```
<main.h>

#define method1  1
#define method2  5
```

Supposed that `method1`, `method2` is defined in main.h.

Is it possible that output filename will be `(method1)_(method2).exe` as `1_5.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

No.

A #define in a header file only exists in the files that include that header file.  The project settings do not include that header file so it is impossible.